# Can't instantiate JQ Mobile pagecontainer widget

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am new to JQuery Mobile and am having difficulty instantiating the
pagecontainer widget. I have read the JQ Mobile documentation, with some excerpts here, and looked for solutions here on SO but I keep getting the same error: "undefined is not a function".

This note and code example are from the documentation on the widget:

Note: The pagecontainer widget is designed to be a singleton instantiated by the framework on the body element. This limitation will be removed in future versions of jQuery Mobile.

Documentation code examples:

Initialize the pagecontainer with the defaults option specified:

```
$( ".selector" ).pagecontainer({ defaults: true });
```

Initialize the pagecontainer with the create callback specified:

```
$( ".selector" ).pagecontainer({
  create: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

So, with this information I am using "body" as the selector however I keep getting "undefined is not a function" message using either code example. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="one">
<div data-role="header"></div>
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">   
    <p><a href="#map-page" data-role="button" data-transition="slide">Show Map Page</a></p> 
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="a"></div>
</div>
<!-- Start of page: #map-page -->
<div data-role="page" id="map-page" data-url="map-page" data-add-back-btn="true">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
   <h1>Maps</h1>
</div>
<div role="main" class="ui-content" id="map-canvas">
    <!-- map loads here... -->
</div>
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form class="full-width-slider">
        <label for="slider-12" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Slider:</label>
        <input type="range" name="slider-12" id="slider-12" min="0" max="100" value="50">
    </form>
    <?php require "selectform3.php"; ?>
</div>
</div><!-- map page -->
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#one", function (e) {
    console.log(e);

    $("body").pagecontainer({
        defaults: true
    });
    var defaults = $("body").pagecontainer("option", "defaults");
    console.log(defaults); //undefined is not a function

    $("body").pagecontainer({
        create: function (event, ui) {
            console.log(event) //undefined is not a function
        }
    });

});

$("#map-page").on("pagebeforecreate", function () {
    $.getScript("googlemaps2.js")
        .done(function (script, textStatus) {})
        .fail(function (jqxhr, settings, exception) {
        console.log("Triggered ajaxError handler.");
    });
});

$("#map-page").on('pagecreate', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: forget about documentation, what do you want to achieve? Also, you aren't closing _content_ div in first page, this will mess up the whole structure.

Comment: I want to know how to instantiate the widget

Answer (score 1):

First, I upgraded JQ to v 1.11.1 and the widget is working as expected in the documentation. Having done that, this is how I was able to use the widget to change the theme of a header from "b" to "a":

"intitialize" the widget on the header using the JQM selector:

$( "div:jqmData(role='header')" ).pagecontainer();

per documentation: When finding elements by their jQuery Mobile data  attribute, please use the custom selector :jqmData().
http://api.jquerymobile.com/jqmData/

//set the theme option, after initialization:

$( "div:jqmData(role='header')").pagecontainer("option", "theme", "a");